# How do I make an img stretch to its container's width, regardless of it's height?

Tags: css, image

.. expecting the picture to get "cropped" at the top and bottom. I only want it to fit the width 100%, and wish to become bigger than the height, but not leave the certain container.

How is that done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is a bit vauge if you meant you wanted an img to stretch to the full width off a container but the height too get cut off then you want something like this.

```
.container{
    width:300px;
    height:300px;
    overflow:hidden;
    display:block;}

.container img{
    width:100%;
    vertical-align:middle;
   }
```

Answer (score 1):

Just set the container's css `overflow` property to `hidden`, give it a fixed size, put your image inside with a fixed width, and done :)

Well, almost done. To get it cropped at the top and bottom, you need to get the image vertically centered in the box. One hack to achieve this is to have tiny text nodes on either side of the image, having a `line-height` the same as the container div height. Giving the image `vertical-align:middle` should center it vertically within your div.